# Google App Engine keeps spinning up "phantom" instances

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I am trying to set up an email server, where people can email my app, and my app will process the information given in the body.

I was testing it last night and sent a bunch of emails to the server (22), but the last message went out at about 10pm eastern. For whatever reason, when looking at the server logs this morning, it is still saying that it is receiving emails from my email address (which it definitely isn't..). I was doing a lot of debugging and I'm wondering if GAE is recycling instances somehow if there was an error? The behavior seems incredibly odd and I don't know how to stop it.

From my app.yaml, the instance is only loaded up when an email is received, and no one else according to GAE's logs is emailing my server.

Thanks!

Here's a bit from my logs:

```
2014-03-30 06:58:50.668 /_ah/mail/[emailaddress]@[myappname].appspotmail.com 500 519ms 2kb     module=default version=main
0.1.0.20 - - [30/Mar/2014:03:58:50 -0700] "POST /_ah/mail/[emailaddress]@[myappname].appspotmail.com HTTP/1.1" 500 2076 - - "   [myappname].appspot.com" ms=520 cpu_ms=21 cpm_usd=0.200348 app_engine_release=1.9.1    instance=00c61b117cc3c88c83fa0e016a492569707566
I 2014-03-30 06:58:50.164
Received a message from: [my personal email address]
```

Except I definitely didn't send an email at 6:58am..

Comment: I've not read the docs but your example request returned a 500 status, so it's possible it's retrying failed requests – much as a task queue does.

Comment: I think that's what it's doing -- do you know how to stop it from wanting to retry?

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid as I've not done any inbound mail handling and the docs are a bit thin on the topic. Does inbound mail show up under your Task Queues at all in the console?  Alternatively, you might just have to change/fix your code to not return a 500 if you don't want retries to occur.  You could perhaps log errors and return a 200, for example.